# How to add javascript code in virtue mart's 2 product description?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

i have virtuemart version 2.0.4 and cant add javascript code like - `<a href="javascript:return false;" >link</a>`
in the product's description. It always renders it as `<a>link</a>`, though joomla handles the code right.
Thanks for help

Comment: try `onclick="return false"` It might be filtering pseudoprotocols for security issues real or imagined.

Comment: @ErikReppen, Unfortunately this didnt work. Same result.

Comment: try to use javascript:; It fails then try # It will defenitly works